# Ionic2's <ion-slide>

Tags: android, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've been trying to use Ionic2 to develop an app but I've been having some trouble because of the lack of information that I find.

I hope that I can make this easy to understand, but my main problem is that  generates a slider that is either full-screen or the slide itself occupies the whole width of the screen.

However, this is not what I want. I want a section with many different pictures with their corresponding captions. But since you will only be able to see a couple pics on-screen you will have to scroll horizontally to see the rest. Also, the scrolling would have to be smoother than in the

I have started web and app developing, so forgive me if this is too basic and easy. How could you do horizontally scrollable section with Ionic2?

This is what I have:

HTML

```
    <div class="tus-anuncios-slider-slides">
        <ion-slides pager (change)="onSlideChanged($event)" (move)="onSlideMove($event)" loop="true" autoplay="true">

        <ion-slide>
            <div class="tus-anuncios-slider-slides-1">
                <img src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg">
                <p>Cuidador de Mascotas</p>
            </div>
        </ion-slide>



        <ion-slide>
            <div class="tus-anuncios-slider-slides-2">
                <img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53f8d1ace4b0f0d1ac1219aa/56717c8da2bab81949502181/56717ebd25981dd75e7d5a89/1450278591780/Aviator+Boy.jpg?format=1500w">
               <p>Niñera con experienc...</p>
            </div>
        </ion-slide>


        <ion-slide>
            <div class="tus-anuncios-slider-slides-3">
                <img src="https://orangecountyeldercare.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/dreamstime_m_16251832.jpg">
                <p>Cuidado de ancianos</p>
            </div>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If I understand your question but to answer you, Yes its possible to do it Not in full-screen:

> I want a section with many different pictures with their corresponding
>   captions.

```
<ion-slides> 
    <ion-slide>
        <ion-card>
            <img src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg" />
            <ion-card-content>
                <ion-card-title>
                    Nine Inch Nails Live
                </ion-card-title>
                <p>Cuidador de Mascotas</p>
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>

    <ion-slide>
        <ion-card>
            <img src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg" />
            <ion-card-content>
                <ion-card-title>
                    Nine Inch Nails Live
                </ion-card-title>
                <p>Ninera con experienc...</p>
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-item-group>
<ion-item-divider color="light">PHOTOS<span style="float:right;">MORE</span></ion-item-divider>
</ion-item-group>


<ion-scroll scrollX="true" class="ion-scroll-thumbnail">           
<img width="90" height="90" class="avatarImage" src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg">
<img width="90" height="90" class="avatarImage" src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg">

<img width="90" height="90" class="avatarImage" src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg">

<img width="90" height="90" class="avatarImage" src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg">

<img width="90" height="90" class="avatarImage" src="http://www.wormsandgermsblog.com/files/2009/02/PETS_0803_dog_bath1.jpg">

</ion-scroll> 

/* CSS */

.ion-scroll-thumbnail {
white-space: nowrap;
height: 90px;
}
```